# How to keep dash in powershell read-host variable

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script to activate a licence key.

I asked the user to enter the licence key in a read-host variable. The licence key format is : XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

But it seems that the dash "-" was removed from the variable. I've read that I need tu use regex. But I don't how to do it.
I've found that my regex expression is :

```
^([A-Z0-9]{5}-){4}[A-Z0-9]{5}$
```

My entire script is :

```
$licence_id = read-host "Enter licence key"
$Arguments = "-x proxy.configuration `""

Set-Location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Audinate\Dante Virtual Soundcard\Tools\'
.\dvs_licenser.exe -l $licence_id $Arguments
```

If you can help me, I'm quite novice in powershell & regex

Comment: `Read-Host` preserves whatever characters you type. If `-` chars. get removed, perhaps your `.exe` does it? Also, `$Arguments` should be assigned as `$Arguments = '-x', 'proxy.configuration'`

Comment: A different approach would be required to _ensure_ that the dashes are in the right places, even if the user didn't type them that way.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for you tips. Yes my .exe do it.
Have you a idea for a different approach ?

Comment: Something like `$licence_id = $licence_id -replace '-' -split '(.{5})' -ne '' -join '-'` should make sure the dashes are in there where they should be.

Comment: @mklement0 That not the exe who removed the `-` but I think it's the `read-host`

Comment: `Read-Host` doesn't remove `-` (nor any other characters typed by the user). If so, that would be a serious bug, and we'd need a [mcve].